# Improve multidimensional dictionary loop efficiency

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

I'm taking first steps with python and trying to iterate over multidimensional dictionary, while checking if key exists and not None.
Just to make it clear, the code works! But I feel that there should be a better way to implement it:

```
for key in sites[website_name]: 
    if 'revenue' in sites[website_name][key]:
        if sites[website_name][key]['revenue'] is not None:
            totalSiteIncome += sites[website_name][key]['revenue']
        else:
            sites[website_name][key]['revenue'] = 0
    if 'spent' in sites[website_name][key]:
        if sites[website_name][key]['spent'] is not None:
            totalSiteSpent += sites[website_name][key]['spent']
        else:
            sites[website_name][key]['spent'] = 0
```

Any idea if and how can I improve the loop?

Keep in mind, looking for best practice here, thx!

Comment: Use dict.get() to safely get values without causing KeyError: http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-code-patterns/correctness/not_using_get_to_return_a_default_value_from_a_dictionary.html 
Instead of checking for not None, why don't you just do `if variable:` If it is None, it will not pass the check.

Comment: Note that "arrays" are existing objects in certain python modules, and they are very different from dicts, and also different from lists and tuples.

Comment: Multidimensional _dictionary_ or _array_? The first one can't really be multidimensional and the second one is the name of a Python module as `["this", "is", "a", "LIST"]`.

Comment: this is a good candidate for the code review board

Comment: I highly recommend you look at pandas and numpy: https://www.scipy.org. They'll rock your world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a sample of the `sites[website_name]` dictionary would really be helpful but if I understand you correctly, this is how I would do it:

```
totalSiteIncome = sum(x.get('revenue', 0.0) for x in sites[website_name])
totalSiteSpent = sum(x.get('spent', 0.0) for x in sites[website_name])
```

As mentioned in the comments, `.get()` allows you not to care whether the key is there or not and it takes a default argument in case it isn't (in this case 0). Other than that is just a generator in the `sum()` function.

In english the first line would read:

*"get me all the `revenues` if they exist from every website in my `site` dictionary and sum them. If the `revenue` is not logged, assume 0"*

As a sidenote, in your code, the `totalSiteIncome` and `totalSiteSpent` have to be **initialised** too, otherwise it whould not run. In my version they don't have to be and if they are their values will be overwritten.

Comment: I usually prefer to use the if clause of the generator to check if they key exists instead of `.get(['...'], 0)` as it is more readable

Comment: @Adirio it is more readable if you are not used to it. But i would humbly suggest getting since it is most likely much faster. The `setdefault()` is a similar story

Comment: That would need to be timed but this application doesn't seem to be needing that kind of speed. And afterall, we are writting python, readability is one of its strengths while speed isn't. The reason I would go for the readable part is because he seems not to be a main-python programmer, as the loops aren't pythonic.

Comment: @improving efficiency while maintaining a high level of readability for non python-trained eyes sounds like a too difficult task for my coding skills. But fair enough.

Comment: I agree, readability and efficiency are often hard to accomplish at the same time. Just thought I may mention it so that you could add it to your answer if you wish as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach could be useful if you need a solution that is agnostic to the nesting level of the target fields (`revenue` and `spent`). Also could be useful if you want to add more and more fields, as with this solution you don't need to repeat the code for each new field.

Besides that, there are some downsides to my suggestion, comparing to your solution: it's using recursion, which is less readable, and also a flag (`return_totals`), which feels hacky. Just adding my 5 cents to the brainstorm.

```
import collections

def _update(input_dict, target_fields, totals = {}, return_totals=True):
    result = {}
    for k, v in input_dict.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            r = _update(input_dict[k], target_fields, totals, return_totals=False)
            result[k] = r
        else:
            if k in target_fields: 
                result[k] = input_dict[k] or 0
                if k not in totals:
                    totals[k] = 0
                totals[k] += result[k]
            else:
                result[k] = input_dict[k]
    if return_totals:
        return {
            'updated_dictionary': result,
            'totals': totals,
        }
    return result

new_sites = _update(input_dict = sites, target_fields = ['revenue', 'spent'])

print 'updated_dictionary:'
print new_sites['updated_dictionary']
print 'totals:'
print new_sites['totals']
```

Answer (score 0):

dictionaries should be iterated using their iterator methods, for example `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()`.

## dict.keys():

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
for key in d.keys():
    print(key)
```

Output:

```
a
b
```

## dict.values():

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
for value in d.values():
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

## dict.items():

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key + " -> " + value)
```

Output:

```
a -> 1
b -> 2
```

#### NOTE:

This methods work both in Python2 and Python3, but are only real iterators (improving efficiency) in Python3. The iterators in Python2 are called `dir.iterkeys()`, `dir.itervalues()` and `dir.iteritems()` respectively.